# Is it The Axiom of Power Set that guarantees the existence of (all) subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Axiom of Power Set asserts that:

> For any set $S$, there exists a set $\wp$ such that $X \in \wp$ if and only if $X\subseteq S$.

That is, *if* something is a subset of $S$, *then* it's a member of $\wp$, and $\wp$ contains nothing but subsets of $S$.

However, the way I see it, the axiom does not guarantees the existence of subsets of $S$ at first. Possibly we can tell whether something is a subset of $S$ or not, but how can we ascertain the existence of all of them?

Comment: Would it not be enough to know about the existence of the set $S$ ? Then we have our set with elements. We can then talk about a group of elements being contained within $S$ ?

Comment: I think it's the Axiom of Subsets (aka Separation aka Specification) that guarantees the existence of subsets. The Power Set Axiom tells us that there are *not too many* subsets of a given set $S$; it says that the class of all subsets of $S$ is a *set* rather than a proper class.

Comment: The axiom schema of specification guarantees the existence of subsets.

Comment: But if the axioma schema of specification guaranteed the existence of all subsets of a particular set, wouldn't the axiomas of pairing and union suffice to obtain $\wp$?

Comment: Of which subsets? To construct a wide variety, we use many tools, including Separation (if included) or Replacement. But one can prove the existence of some without.

Comment: How can we prove the existence of all subsets of a set?

Comment: All subsets of a set exist be definition: Even if there were a set that has no subsets, all of its subsets would exist; that statement would then be vacuously true. However, from the subset definition it immediately follows that the empty set is a subset of every set, so every set has at least one subset (for the empty set, it's the only  subset).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this question can be answered by  another thorough read of the axiom. Note that it says,

> for every $S$, **there exists** a set $P(S)$ such that ...etc.

The whole point of the axiom is to **declare the existence of the set of subsets**. I'll elaborate:

We have the definition: $X$ is a subset of $S$ (notation $X\subset S$) $\iff$ $(\forall x)(x\in X\implies x\in S)$.
Since sets exist, this is a solid definition. Using this definition, we can see that subsets (of any set) exist, because $\emptyset $ and $S$ always satisfy this definition. How many there are in total, we don't know yet.

When we make the axioms, we are deciding which objects we will call sets, and which objects we will not call sets. At a certain point we decide that we don't want $\{ X\mid X\subset S\}$ to be a proper class (i.e. not a set).  So we create the rule (axiom) that $\{ X\mid X\subset S\}$ is a set, for all sets $S$. For convenience we use the notation: $P(S)=\{ X\mid X\subset S\}$.

Now let's sum this up:

- Subsets exits, because sets exist.
- Any subset of a set $S$, will belong to $P(S)$, because that's simply how we defined $P(S)$.
- The Power Set Axiom now says: Henceforth, we will all agree that we consider $P(S)$ to be a set for every set $S$.

Comment: @celtschk You're right I should have written "set of all subsets". But wouldn't the existence of a subset-free set just be a logical inconsistency. Suppose we have a subset-free set $X$. But we also have $x\in \emptyset\implies x\in X$, a contradiction. So the existence of a subset would follow from the existence of $\emptyset$. The Power Set Axiom says that the class of all subsets of $X$ is a set.

Comment: Good point. Indeed, you don't really need the power set axiom for that; from the subset definition it follows that any set is subset of itself, so the subset-free set would already be self-contradictory without considering *any* of the set axioms (you don't even need to know what $\in$ means!).

Comment: @Fred Be careful. You're not differentiating between sets and elements of sets. In your analogy: If $X$ is the set of all unicorns (we'll assume that it is indeed a set), then $X$ **does exist**. It is the set of all unicorns. What **doesn't exist** is an $x$, for which $x\in X$. So in your last sentence: $X\subset S\iff X\in \wp$ even if $X$ is **empty** ('cause that's what's going on).

Comment: @gebruiker Yes, it was a bad analogy indeed. But, can you see my point: for any set with $n$ elements, how can we assure the existence of the $2^n$ subsets? It seems that the axiom of power set simply certifies that whatever subset of a particular set will belong to its power set, but it doesn't guarantees that all those subsets exist in the first place...

Comment: Well, if the existence of a nonempty set, say $S=\{a, b, c, d, ...\}$, implies the existence of their elements as sets, I think it automatically implies the existence of all possible subsets. We can form $\{a\}, \{b\},\{c\}, ...$ and $\{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\}, ...$. Then the axiom of power set serves only to *collect* all those subsets in a  single set. But if we are not able to form those primitive sets my question would persist...

Comment: @Fred Try to realise what the axioms are for. I made an edit to my answer. Do things make sense now?

Comment: I understand your answer. What would happen in this specific case? $\exists A(A=\{a, b\})$. Then $\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}$ and $A$ are subsets of it and belong to $\wp (A)$. But, for me the only obvious existences are of $\emptyset$ and $A$ itself. Does the statement of the axiom that $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are members of $\wp (A)$ gives rise to their very existences? That was my initial point on the question.

Comment: @Fred No it does not. The axiom only says that $\big\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\big\}$ is a set. Actually constructing the elements of $\wp(A)$ is a bit trickier.